# What the difference between "svn ls -rNNN" and "svn ls URL@NNN"?

Tags: svn

I try list a SVN repo directory

```
svn ls -r21316 https://mysvnserver.com/repos/project1/trunk/development
```

I get an error

```
svn: warning: W160013: '/repos/project1/!svn/bc/21361/trunk/development' path not found
svn: E200009: Could not list all targets because some targets don't exist
```

But if I try

```
svn ls https://mysvnserver.com/repos/project1/trunk/development@21316
```

It works fine.

What the difference between this statements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The notation `-rNNN` is called  **operative revision**, the notation `somePath@NNN` is called **peg revision**.

The difference is, that the operative revision can be ambiguous: When you moved a folder in a previous revision it is not possible to determine which object you want to see.
If you use peg revision it tells svn that you want to see the object which was present at the given revision at this place.

The SVN Book has good explanation, which is to long to copy here: [Peg and Operative Revisions](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.advanced.pegrevs.html)